# Aggregate totals of a ViewSet results in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a ViewSet which outputs a set of results:

```
{
    "count": 19355,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "duration": 5,
            ...
        },
        {
            "duration": 5,
            ...
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

I would like to aggregate the totals of the duration of the results, right in that handy little top area next to "count". I know how to do this in a queryset, using annotate and sum, but I don't see a way to get it into the ViewSet output.

Desired output for this data set would be:

```
{
    "count": 19355,
    "total_duration": 10,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "duration": 5,
            ...
        },
        {
            "duration": 5,
            ...
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

I appreciate the help!

Comment: Looking at the output of the viewset, you are using Pagination, aren't you? Do you want `total_duration` to be the sum of durations of the page or of the whole queryset ?

Comment: Yes I am, and I would like it to be the total of the whole queryset. Which I suppose could require another db query, and that's fine. I'd just rather not create a whole new endpoint just for aggregates.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would suggest implementing this using a dedicated [Pagination](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination) class.

```
class PaginationWithAggregates(pagination.LimitOffsetPagination):
    def paginate_queryset(self, queryset, request, view=None):
        self.total_duration = queryset.aggregate(total_duration=Sum('duration'))['total_duration']
        return super(PaginationWithAggregates, self).paginate_queryset(queryset, request, view)

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        paginated_response = super(PaginationWithAggregates, self).get_paginated_response(data)
        paginated_response.data['total_duration'] = self.total_duration
        return paginated_response
```

Don't forget to declare this pagination class on your GenericView.

Comment: Ingenious! Never thought to put this in the pagination class. Worked like a charm (had to make some edits to your solution to move the total_duration to the data payload, rather than the response header.) Thank you!

Comment: Amazing! This works totally, saved me hours. Thank you @Michael. :)